# How to specify function in this case

Tags: function-construction

```
y = x;
f[x_] := y;
```

Then, when I want to evaluate `f[1]`, I get `y` but I want to get `1`.

How to work with such cases?

p.s. I tried `f[z_]:=Function[{x},y][z]`, but it doesn't work also.

Comment: `f[x_] := Evaluate@y`  or `f[x_] = y`

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, when you type `f[x_] := ` then you are saying to look for any place that the *pattern* `x` appears on the right hand side, but **do not evaluate** the right hand side.  But your pattern `x` only appears on the RHS if you **do** evaluate it.  So those are two methods to make sure that the RHS is evaluated when you define the function.

Comment: This is a tricky question because you may want `y` to not evaluate yet to be able to inject it to the definition and avoid variables renaming. Then you can go with: `y := x; Hold[f[x_] := y] /. OwnValues[y] // ReleaseHold` etc etc, dense topic :) more real-word case would help.

Comment: I would expect `f[1]` to eval to `x` not `y` ..

Comment: JasonB thank you. Works well enough!!